# In mapbox , how can I return my location when I click the button on android

Tags: android, location, mapbox

How can I return my location when I click the button, just like google map.
I would like to click a button and show my location in mapbox.
what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `LocationComponent` via instructions here https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/location-component/

There's also a basic `LocationComponent` example in the Mapbox Android demo app: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/location/LocationComponentActivity.java

Once everything's set up, you're going to move the Mapbox map camera to the last known location in the button `onClick()`.

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();

        mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
          new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude())));

      }
});
```

`animateCamera()` is another option instead of `moveCamera()` if you'd like.